# CakePHP - Quick way to get /controller/action path?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

Is there a Controller property that will allow me to get just `/controller/action` from the URL without any additional parameters there might be?

At the moment I am having to join `$this->name . '/' . $this->action`.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: To pass to my login page as a redirect

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't want to construct the string `/users/login`, you want *the URL that corresponds to the login action of your users controller* (for example). That is not necessarily the same as `/users/login`, and you should not hardcode it!

To get a URL that will lead to a controller action, use reverse routing:

```
Router::url(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
//or
Router::url(array('controller' => $this->name, 'action' => $this->action));
```

Yes, that's even longer, but it's the correct way to do it. If one day you decide you want the login URL to be `/login` or `/members/entrance` instead of `/users/login`, you only need to define an appropriate route in `routes.php` without rewriting all your hardcoded links.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->here
```

Available in view and controller. Minor note: It's getting removed in 2.0.

Comment: I think `$here` includes any additional URL parameters.

Comment: @BadHorsie Which as you want to use it for a login redirect, I would say are *quite* relevant. If you just want the controller and action then just join the controller and action like you have been!

Comment: No, I don't want the extra parameters.  Thanks, I'll just carry on with joining the controller/action.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to use [HtmlHelper::url](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url) method in 2.x.

```
$this->Html->url(array(
  "controller" => "controller",
  "action" => "action",
  "parameter"
));
```

For CakePHP 3.x, [UrlHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html) is a good choice:

```
$this->Url->build([
  "controller" => "controller",
  "action" => "action",
  "parameter"
]);
```

Both examples produce

```
/controller/action/parameter
```